# How do I deal with data changes every time there are new objects available in Parse?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In my app, I update `PFObject`s very frequently and save them locally with the Parse's local datastore feature. Every time the user launches my app, I'd like to check if there is new data available and if so, update the objects.

When the user opens the app, I retrieve the new objects and compares them with the ones already in memory. If they are not equal, then it replaces the new objects with the ones just fetched.

How do I deal with data changes every time there are new objects available in Parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `updatedAt` property on the remote version of the object and update the object if it is newer. (Also would need to check for any completely new objects in your remote database)

But if you're going to retrieve the objects from Parse anyway, then why not just replace them regardless?

If you don't have that much data, you could run a Parse query for the most recently updated object, and compare that against local data, and download and replace the local data with all the remote data only when its latest update is older than the remote database's latest update.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shim. I think I'd also need to check for deleted objects in Parse that are locally stored in the app, right? As you said, it makes a lot of sense if I just replace everything.

Comment: Instead of straight up deleting objects, you could add a 'hidden', 'deleted' flag on the object and then delete them later